# begin() and end() free function overload on template

Tags: templates, c++11, boost, c++14, non-member-functions

I have a templated class, `Iterable`; for which I want to overload the `begin()` and `end()` free functions. It stores data as a `vector` of `unique_ptr`, but the interface uses `boost::indirect_iterator` for convenience.

My code builds and runs under `CLang-3.5`, but I tried on `g++-4.9` and it did not. But I do not know why ? (And which compiler has the right behaviour).

```
template<typename T>
using SimpleVec = std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>;

template <typename T,
          template <typename> class Container = SimpleVec,
          class String = std::string>
class Iterable
{
        template <typename friendT,
                  template <typename> class friendContainer,
                  class friendString>
        friend boost::indirect_iterator<typename friendContainer<std::unique_ptr<friendT>>::iterator>
            begin(Iterable<friendT, friendContainer, friendString>& i);

        template <typename friendT,
                  template <typename> class friendContainer,
                  class friendString>
        friend boost::indirect_iterator<typename friendContainer<std::unique_ptr<friendT>>::iterator>
            end(Iterable<friendT, friendContainer, friendString>& i);
};
```

And the free functions :

```
template <typename T,
          template <typename> class Container = SimpleVec,
          class String = std::string>
boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>
    begin(Iterable<T, Container, String>& i)
{
    return boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>(begin(i._c));
}

template <typename T,
          template <typename> class Container = SimpleVec,
          class String = std::string>
boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>
    end(Iterable<T, Container, String>& i)
{
    return boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>(end(i._c));
}
```

On `g++`, the error is :

```
../../API/net/session/ClientSession.h:83:29: error: call of overloaded 'begin(GroupManager&)' is ambiguous
      for(auto& grp : groups())
                             ^
../../API/net/session/ClientSession.h:83:29: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../../API/net/session/../permission/full/PermissionManager.h:5:0,
                 from ../../API/net/session/Session.h:3,
                 from ../../API/net/session/ClientSession.h:2,
                 from ../../API/net/session/ClientSessionBuilder.h:2,
                 from ../client/main.cpp:2:
../../API/net/session/../permission/full/../../Iterable.h:22:4: note: boost::indirect_iterator<typename friendContainer<std::unique_ptr<friendT> >::iterator> begin(Iterable<friendT, friendContainer, friendString>&) [with friendT = Group; friendContainer = SimpleVec; friendString = std::basic_string<char>; T = Permission; Container = SimpleVec; String = std::basic_string<char>; typename friendContainer<std::unique_ptr<friendT> >::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<Group, std::default_delete<Group> >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Group, std::default_delete<Group> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Group, std::default_delete<Group> > > > >]
    begin(Iterable<friendT, friendContainer, friendString>& i);
    ^
../../API/net/session/../permission/full/../../Iterable.h:142:2: note: boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<_Tp> >::iterator> begin(Iterable<T, Container, String>&) [with T = Group; Container = SimpleVec; String = std::basic_string<char>; typename Container<std::unique_ptr<_Tp> >::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<Group, std::default_delete<Group> >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Group, std::default_delete<Group> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Group, std::default_delete<Group> > > > >]
  begin(Iterable<T, Container, String>& i)
  ^
```

So it looks like `g++` sees the `friend` declaration as another function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to find an answer (which is much more readable) thanks to @sehe's answer and [this cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends).

```
template <typename T,
          template <typename> class Container = SimpleVec,
          class String = std::string>
class Iterable
{
        friend boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>
            begin(Iterable& i)
        {
            return boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>(begin(i._c));
        }

        friend boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>
            end(Iterable& i)
        {
            return boost::indirect_iterator<typename Container<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator>(end(i._c));
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

An in-class friend function acts as a free function declared in the containing scope.

It sees the friend declaration as another function *because it is* (in fact, another function template generating unbounded functions, all different from the free function).

Had the templates been identical, you would get a different diagnostic:

```
main.cpp:13:13: error: redefinition of 'begin'
char const* begin(X const&)   { return data; }
            ^
main.cpp:9:24: note: previous definition is here
    friend char const* begin(X const&)   { return data; }
                       ^
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b68732e4d7254932)**

Comment: @Yakk oops. Fixed. The message is much more descriptive now too. Although, indeed, the OP's problem was more with template functions rather than in-class definition of free functions, possibly. My +1 is with the other answer

Comment: the next question is, how are the OP's two versions non-identical?  And the OP's `friend` had no body, your does.

Comment: @Yakk. Sigh. [I messed this up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/606a4d268719ca09), didn't I :| You're right. Except for suggesting inline definitions I didn't explain any of the mystery. Will delete in the morning. Cheers